# Know which link directed me to page

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I want to create a webpage with a dynamic headline that changes according to the link I clicked on in another page.

Lets say that I have page with two links

```
<a href="somePage.html">link 1</a>
<a href="somePage.html">link 2</a>
```

and in "somePage.html" I have a headline that I want to modify according to the link I clicked (link 1 or link 2).

```
<h2>you were directed from [here I should insert link 1 or link 2] </h2>
```

I can only use html, css and JS and the logic has to be on the frontend.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can add query param to each link:

```
<a href="somePage.html?page=link 1">link 1</a>
<a href="somePage.html?page=link 2">link 2</a>

<div id='redirected-from'></div>

<script>
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    let text = urlParams.get('page');
    // escape &, <, >, " and '
    linkText = text.replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
     .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
     .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
     .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
     .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");

    document.getElementById("redirected-from").innerHTML = `<h2>You were directed from ${linkText}</h2>`
</script>
```

Comment: Never inject raw HTML from the query string into a page. It must be checked for safety.

Comment: Not really. You can get the new line effect with non-breaking spaces. It just doesn't have the nice horizontal rules. https://imgur.com/a/Mgevvgk